# How to use MeshGrid method in Accord.Math Matrix Class?

Tags: c#

I am using the Accord.Math Namespace for Visual Studio in c#.

I am trying to use the method MeshGrid<> under the Matrix class for the Accord.Math namespace. However, I am unsure how to implement this method even after reading the documentation for it seen here:
http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Math_Matrix_MeshGrid__1.htm

Can anybody show me how to properly implement this method?

I have two Double[,] variables named xa and ya that I am trying to pass to MeshGrid. I have tried calling by using:

```
var q = Matrix.MeshGrid(xa,ya);
```

But for this is says that the type arguments cannot be inferred from their usage.

The output of MeshGrid is a 2-Tuple.
T1 is T[,]
T2 is T[,]

Answer (score 1):

The `Matrix.MeshGrid` method takes inputs as type of `T[]` (not `T[,]`).

Method signature:

```
public static Tuple<T[,], T[,]> MeshGrid<T>(this T[] sequence1, T[] sequence2);
```

Example:

```
var xi = new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var yi = new double[] {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
Tuple<double[,], double[,]> grid = Matrix.MeshGrid(xi, yi);
```